# PushPlugin and Meteor 0.9.2 RC

Tags: cordova, meteor

I would like to implement push notifications with Meteor 0.9.2 RC (ie new Cordova capability in Meteor).

I think the way to do this is with [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)?

I also see https://github.com/SpaceCapsule/Meteor-phonegap-push so not sure if one way is preferred over the other?

If you have some experience on what is the best way to go, please let me know?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am currently struggling on the same issue, here is what I have learned:

- **PushPlugin** (2.2.1) is for your app **client** and enables your mobile application to register for push notifications and get your mobile device specific token.
- **Apn**(https://github.com/argon/node-apn) for node.js, on which meteor server is built upon, or **Meteor-phonegap-push** (https://github.com/SpaceCapsule/Meteor-phonegap-push) if you want a "true" meteor package, are server side plugins that will enable your Meteor server to push notifications to the intermediate Apple or Google Notification server, that then will notify the mobile device.

I managed to **make everything work in development environment** (with meteor run ios-device -p and the sandboxed push gateway iOS notification server)  as they explain in their docs and by following a few tutorials on the internet

**BUT...**

Watch out if you want to do **production or Ad Hoc distribution** ! I was not able to make PushPlugin work consistently by using meteor build -p, and the new meteor phonegap system seems to have problems of its own that go in top of that, so if you are new to all this, and want to distribute your app fast to testers or stuff, I would not recommend this approach for the moment, there is a lack of documentation.

Hope i helped, good luck

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.. ok going to give this a go when I come up for air.... soon I hope.